# Data download for Chinese meteorological satellites

Tags: data-request, weather, china

Data for NOAA meteorological satellites can be downloaded through the NOAA CLASS archive.

Where, if anywhere, can I download data for the Chinese FY-3* meteorological satellites?

Comment: looking for something like this: http://satellite.cma.gov.cn/arssen/ ? It appears you have to pay for some, if not most, of the data though.

Comment: Also search http://govinfo.nlc.gov.cn/

Comment: @fgregg OK I posted an answer

Comment: @fgregg Because I know nothing about satellites and I was trying to understand the question first.

Comment: gerrit, do you want data **ABOUT** these satellites (position, age, name, technologies, etc) or data **TAKEN BY** these satellites (images, measures)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try http://satellite.cma.gov.cn/portalsite/Data/Satellite.aspx?currentculture=en-US

[image: Satellite data download page]

You can then download a "quickview" by clicking the little "picture" icon:
[image]

The full resolution data seemingly require payment.

---Information below is OBSOLETE. ---

Try [FENGYUN Satellite Data Center](http://satellite.cma.gov.cn/arssen/). Getting the data from it can be a little tricky.

**First click one of the icons:**

[image: screenshot 1]

**In the next page, remember to select one of the "products" before clicking "next":**
[image]

**I haven't really used the system. It seems you need to pay for the data. However, "quickviews" are free:**

[image]

Comment: I removed my reference to the 风云 satellite data center in my answer since you found this.

Comment: Andy, the link now returns an error...

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for pointing out. I think they changed the website interface and I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I first searched the [Chinese Government's Public Information site](http://govinfo.nlc.gov.cn/) for `FY-3` and [found 8 articles](http://govinfo.nlc.gov.cn/search/nlc_search.jsp?siteid=lmzy&keyword=FY%EF%BC%8D3&page=1) related to this kind of satellite, but no data sets. The articles had to do with beginning to use these satellites for various meteorological projects (November 2009) and the development of a system for processing this data (articles from 2009-2011). I did not see any actual data sets, however.

Comment: If you search "风云" (which FY stands for) on the govinfo site, you'll get 738 results. :)

Comment: Yes "Fengyun." If you answer, I'll gladly remove the second paragraph of my answer and vote yours up. You clearly know more about it than me - that's why I only commented originally.

Comment: Here are the results if you search "风云": http://govinfo.nlc.gov.cn/search/nlc_search.jsp?siteid=lmzy&keyword=%E9%A3%8E%E4%BA%91&page=1

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the UCS Satellite database. They track over 1000 satellites orbiting the earth.

http://www.ucsusa.org/nuclear_weapons_and_global_security/solutions/space-weapons/ucs-satellite-database.html